# How to inject a repository with typedi and typeorm

Tags: typeorm, typegraphql, typedi

Im using typeorm, typedi and typegraphql (not nest.js) and am trying to inject my typeorm repository into the the service but its not working

```
Container.set("UserRepository", dataSource.getRepository(UserEntity));

@Service()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>) {}

  async createUser({
    name,
    email,
    password,
  }: Input {...}
```

The error im getting is

```
Service with \"MaybeConstructable<Repository>\" identifier was not found in the container. Register it before usage via explicitly calling the \"Container.set\" function or using the \"@Service()\" decorator."
```

even though I can print out the repository with `Container.get(UserRepository)`

Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution:

1. Add the container to the buildSchema function that apollo gives us:

```
  await dataSource.initialize();
  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers,
    emitSchemaFile: true,
    container: Container,
  });
```

2. Set the repositories on bootstrapping the app:

```
export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(UserEntity).extend({});

Container.set("UserRepository", UserRepository);
```

3. Use it in your service:

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject("UserRepository") private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: gotcha. I use pretty much the same strategy apart from the bootstrapping process as I use individual class files to house the Repositories e.g. 
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {}

Comment: Oh nice - I didn't know you could use classes, is it as simple as your snippet?

Comment: correct, just need to add the relevant imports and that's it! also, I suggest making the repository readonly too

Answer (score 0):

try adding this annotation to your injected repo

```
import { InjectRepository } from 'typeorm-typedi-extensions';

constructor(@InjectRepository() private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>) {}
```

you may need to install the [typeorm-typedi-extensions package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-typedi-extensions)

and make sure you have `useContainer(Container);` in your bootstrapping process to register the typeorm container which should be the container from the above package

Comment: I think this answer is out of date with current versions, il post my solution to this

Comment: could you explain which part of this is out of date as I'm currently using this strategy but it seems similar to what you posted

Comment: I **think** the latest typeorm versions are incompatible with typeorm-typedi-extensions package and I remember seeing typeorm back this decision in an issue regarding it

Answer (score 0):

In the service constructor, you need to bind the related functions.
Usually, we see that the functions associated with the Service class may loose "this" so we need to make sure "this" is not lost.
Either make the function(=>) or bind the function in constructor.
Hope this helps.